# Next.js app deployment as ssr app with some hosting provider restrictions

Tags: next.js

I have a shared hosting provider that enables hosting node apps. It has a restriction that the app entry file must be called `app.js` and it must be in folder `/usr/home/username/domains/domain/public_nodeapp`. The app is started automatically (probably by something like `node app.js`) upon first access from the web to the domain.

Is it possible to host a `next.js` app on such a provider as a server-side rendered app (not as static HTML site produced by `next export`)?

After running `next build` which makes a production version of the app, the production version has no `app.js` file and should be started by `next start`. I am not sure whether and how it could be tweaked (perhaps some file moving or renaming) to match the restrictions mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a `app.js` file that is placed in the required place, and then call the function that will be called when you trigger `next start` from the cli.

That means that this file should require https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/cli/next-start.ts and invoke `nextStart`.

```js
// app.js
const startServer = require('next/dist/cli/next-start');

startServer();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it using a custom server eg. express.js

I am doing the same thing for Azure, the only difference is that I need a file called `server.js`

Example:

```
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.all('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    /* eslint no-console: "off" */
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

I hope this helps.