# How do I deploy NextJS to shared hosting cPanel while retaining static generation benefits?

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpanel

So I first built a NextJS app on my local PC, I then uploaded the project to cPanel. I created a NodeJS selector for the project and configured the settings as per the cPanel instructions and all seemed good. When I call npm start on the command line, the project runs perfectly and in the browser.

The issue that I am struggling with is configuring an appropriate startup script to run the NextJS server, without creating a custom server for it (and more specifically, without losing the static optimization capabilities).

I have tried creating an app.js file for the startup script which attempts to import [this next-start](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/cli/next-start.ts) server and call it. (Gave the error 'nextStart is not a function'). The suggestion for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365277/next-js-app-deployment-as-ssr-app-with-some-hosting-provider-restrictions)

I have also tried to run exec('next-start') in the app.js file. This file worked if I called it in command line, however it did not work when added to the cPanel NodeJS selector. The code is as follows:

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');
exec('npm start');
```

I can't use pm2 because it is a shared hosting account and therefore I don't have root access to be able to configure pm2 to restart the process on server restart (incase of crashes etc).

Does anyone have any valid methods of deploying a NextJS server to a cPanel shared hosting account, without compromising NextJS automatic static optimization?